# How to retrieve firebase data with inner key sorting in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: firebase]

I have above structured data in firebase database. I have added digits before every month name, otherwise data was showing as letter ascending order. After adding digits I am facing another problem, 10,11,12 is coming in between 1 and 2. And while retrieving data I am getting result in this sequence.

I have tried, `orderByChild("deposit")` while retrieving data but nothing changed.

How can I retrieve data as digit ascending or month name sequence order?

Comment: i think you need make Ref to 2016 node then call oderbychild

Comment: This is not possible, you should get them and sort them mannualy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Firebase database, the keys are of type String. And when you order string data, it is ordered `lexicographically`.

So for numbers, the normal order is this:

- 1
- 9
- 10
- 11

But for strings, the normal order is this:

- "1"
- "11"
- "19"
- "9"

There is no operator in Firebase, and as far as i know nor in other JSON databases, to change this kind of behavior. Instead, you will have to modify the data to get the behavior you want. So: store values that are in the order you need them when sorted lexicographically. For numbers you can accomplish that by padding them with zeroes:

- "001"
- "009"
- "011"
- "019"

In your case you need to use:

- 01-January
- 02-February
- 03-March
- ...
- 11-November
- 12-December

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I thought about this as last solution.